# Mysql break a condition in bracket

Tags: mysql

I have 2 mysql query :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE !(col1 = 'a' && col2 = 'b');
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 != 'a' AND col2 != 'b';
```

This return a different result, and i want it to be like the second statement (without bracket).

Any idea guys ?,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 queries are different thus you are obtaining different results.
You can verify it by making boolean table

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).  I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Your queries are not equivalent. I think you meant to use De Morgan's Law (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), but you did not distribute correctly.

The correct first statement would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE !(col1 = 'a' OR col2 = 'b');
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference would be `NULL` values.  These fail both `=` and `<>`.

You can get around this using NULL-safe comparisons, such as `<=>`.  So:

```
WHERE NOT (col1 <=> 'a' AND col2 <=> 'b');
```